# Does Python3 need to exist for the use of "py3" inside vim if Python3 is statically with vim?

Tags: python, vim

If `+python3` is shown in the output of `:vesion` which means that Python3 is statically linked with vim, does Python3 need to exist to use `py3` inside vim?

Answer (score 2):

> If +python3 is shown in the output of :vesion which means that Python3 is statically linked with vim,

It doesn't. It means `vim` was compiled with Python3 support but the interpreter library (`libpython.so`) is linked **dynamically**.

> does Python3 need to exist to use py3 inside vim?

Yes, and `vim` must know the path to Python as `vim` needs to find  the interpreter library `libpython.so`. Also `vim` (well, Python) needs some parts of the standard Python library.

Comment: Thanks, could you please tell me what is the difference between `python3` option and `python3/dyn` option? @phd